# rescheduling a meeting in lotus notes programatically using java

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

i have written a webservice for rescheduling a non recurring meeting in lotus notes using domino designer 8.5.3.when i reschedule a meeting for the first time in the **Invitee's** calendar the entry will be removed from the previous date and will be placed in the rescheduled date.But when i reschedule the same meeting for the second time the it will create a meeting in the rescheduled date but the previous entry will not be removed from the calendar.

Hers is what i am doing to reschedule the meeting.i rescheduled a meeting from lotus notes and to reschedule from code i am creating a child document from make response method and i am putting all the properties by checking the properties in the meeeting rescheduled from lotus notes.
So can anyone please tell which property of the document is responsible for removing the calendarDate time property.so that the previous calendar entry will be removed from the calendar.

Comment: thanks Richard for the reply..i didnt post the code as i was replacing more than 100 properties..the code was having more than 100 lines..i thought it would not make sense to post it here..

Comment: You should check out the published C&S schema [link](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cs_schema_toc)here if you are going to roll your own docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues was with the SQUENCENUM property of the document.As i was creating a child document using make response method i was incrementing the SQUENCENUM of the child document only but not of the parent document.And because of that reason the value of SQUENCENUM of the child document will always be 2 and hence it was not removing the previous entry from the **Invitees** calendar.The problem got solved by incrementing the SQUENCENUM of the parent document after each reschedule.

Comment: For NON-repeating meetings the parent doc is the meeting and the child doc represent the responses you get back to that meeting.

For repeating meetings the parent doc is just a place holder and the child docs represent the meetings AND responses to different instances.

This means you should bump the SequenceNum item on the parent when sending reschedules of non-repeating meetings and from the specific child doc when rescheduling a repeating meeting.

For non-reschedule changes you bump the UpdateSeq item instead.